# Shared Preference Value not being Saved

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I'm developing an app where the user inputs a value in the shared preference and is being retrieved to subtract the number of calories.

Right now, I have my calorie app hard coded to 2000. The user has a limit of 2000 to consume per day. I wanted the user to be able to change the amount consumed with the shared preference, but for some reason, it is not being saved. That is why I hard coded it.

PreferenceScreenActivity.java

```
public class PreferenceScreenActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preference);

        // Replace the default view with the preference fragment

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.preference_container,
        new PreferenceScreenFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class PreferenceScreenFragment extends PreferenceFragment 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.activity_preference);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_preference.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="User Settings">
        <EditTextPreference
            android:title="Daily Calorie Amount"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:defaultValue="2000"
            android:key="@string/prefs_key_daily_calorie_amount"
            android:summary="@string/prefs_description_daily_calorie_amount"
        />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

FragmentHome.JAVA

```
public class FragmentHome extends DialogFragment 
implements View.OnClickListener  {
    private TextView caloriesTotal;

    private TextView caloriesRemain;

    private ListView listView;
    private LinearLayout mLayout;

    ImageButton AddEntrybtn;
    CalorieDatabase calorieDB;
    Context context;

    int goalCalories;
    AlarmManager am;

    private int  CaloriesRemain;
    Button mButton;

    //Database
    private DatabaseHandler dba;

    private ArrayList<Food> dbFoods = new ArrayList<>();
    private CustomListViewAdapter foodAdapter;
    private Food myFood ;

    //fragment
    private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    public FragmentHome() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        AddEntrybtn = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.AddItems);

        AddEntrybtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                ((appMain) getActivity()).loadSelection(4);
            }
        });

        caloriesTotal = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.tv_calorie_amount);
        caloriesRemain = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.calorieRemain);
        listView = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.ListId);

        refreshData();

        return myView;
    }


    public void refreshData (){

        dbFoods.clear();

        dba = new DatabaseHandler(getContext());

        ArrayList<Food> foodsFromDB = dba.getFoods();
        int totalCalorie = dba.totalCalories();

        String formattedCalories = Utils.formatNumber(totalCalorie);
        String formattedRemain = Utils.formatNumber( 2000-   totalCalorie);
        *Hard coded 2000 amount here * *this works and does get 2000 but
        want to get the shared value here **

        //setting the editTexts:
        caloriesTotal.setText("Total Calories: " + formattedCalories);
        caloriesRemain.setText(formattedRemain);

        CaloriesRemain = loadPrefs(formattedRemain, totalCalorie);

        SharedPreferences prefs =  
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(),  
            R.xml.activity_preference, false);

        String 
            etCalorieRemain=prefs.getString("prefs_key_daily_calorie_amount", 
            "default_edit_text_value");

        goalCalories = 
            Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("prefs_key_daily_calorie_amount",
            "2000"));


        //Loop
        for (int i = 0; i < foodsFromDB.size(); i ++){
            String name = foodsFromDB.get(i).getFoodName();
            String date = foodsFromDB.get(i).getRecordDate();
            int cal = foodsFromDB.get(i).getCalories();
            int foodId = foodsFromDB.get(i).getFoodId();

            Log.v("Food Id", String.valueOf(foodId));

            myFood= new Food();
            myFood.setFoodId(foodId);
            myFood.setFoodName(name);
            myFood.setCalories(cal);
            myFood.setRecordDate(date);

            dbFoods.add(myFood);
        }
        dba.close();

        //setting food Adapter:
        foodAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getActivity(), 
        R.layout.row_item,dbFoods);
        listView.setAdapter(foodAdapter);
        foodAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //save prefs
    public void savePrefs(String key, int value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =   
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.apply();
    }

    //get prefs
    public int loadPrefs(String key, int value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =  
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        return sharedPreferences.getInt(key, value);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle username = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        String username1 = username.getString("Username");

        TextView userMain= (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.User);
        userMain.setText(username1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

        startActivity( new Intent(getContext(),MainActivity.class));
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.AddItems:
                AddEntry addEntry    = new AddEntry();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FragmentHolder,addEntry)
                    .commit();
                break;

            case R.id.action_settings:
                Intent preferenceScreenIntent = new Intent(getContext(), 
                PreferenceScreenActivity.class);
                startActivity(preferenceScreenIntent);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you have `CaloriesRemain` variable and `savePrefs()` method, but you nowhere use value of the varialbe and method.

Look, if you use PreferenceFragment - it will automatically save and load your preferences from SharedPreferences.

If you need to use value from SharedPreferences in your code - you should request them by your key (`@string/prefs_key_daily_calorie_amount`).

At the moment you use `CaloriesRemain = loadPrefs(formattedRemain, totalCalorie);`, but instead of using `formattedRemain` you should use your key `@string/prefs_key_daily_calorie_amount`. And then use `CaloriesRemain` variable in your code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's because I wasn't sure if that was correct. I didn't know how to implement it. This is my first time working with java and Android Studio.

Comment: goalCalories = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("prefs_key_daily_calorie_amount", "2000"));

Comment: When I changed my class to PreferenceFragment I had problems loading the layout since its a fragment

Comment: int CaloriesLeft = loadPrefs("\"@string/prefs_key_daily_calorie_amount\"",totalCalorie);

I used that and I ran the test and its displaying 0 :/

Comment: If you use `PreferenceFragment` (or `PreferenceActivity`) - it will save your preferences automatically. Otherwise you should save them manually, with your `savePrefs` method. Then you would be able to load preference.